# Is there an easier way to see $(x-1)$ not in $I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, alternative-proof

Let $I=\langle 3, x^3+x^2+1\rangle$ be an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

How do we see that $(x-1)\notin I$?

I have a roundabout way that is kind of clumsy.

Thanks a lot.

---

Suppose to the contrary $(x-1)\in I$.

Then $x-1=3g(x)+f(x)h(x)$, where $f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$.

Write $g(x)=f(x)q(x)+r(x)$, with $\deg r<3$.

Then $x-1=3(fq+r)+fh=f(3q+h)+3r$.

So $x-1-3r=f(3q+h)$. Since the LHS has degree strictly less than $3$, while $f$ has degree $3$, thus $x-1-3r=f(3q+h)=0$.

This implies $x-1=3r(x)$ which is a contradiction by considering the constants in the equation modulo $3$.

Comment: Yes, if $\ (3,f) \supseteq (x\!-\!1)\,$ then reducing mod $3$ shows $(f)\supseteq (x\!-\!1)\,\Rightarrow\,f\mid x\!-\!1$ in $\,\Bbb F_3[x]\ $

Comment: Thanks. Is $f\mid x-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ an obvious contradiction or do we need to justify it? I am worried to conclude that just based on $\deg f>\deg(x-1)$ since $2x^3+x\mid 3x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$.

Comment: @yoyostein : if $x-1 = f(x)g(x)$ for some $g \in \Bbb F_3[x]$, then because $\Bbb F_3$ is an integral domain, the degree of the product is the sum of the degrees, i.e. $1=3+\mathrm{deg}(g)$, which is not possible.

Comment: A higher degree polynomial cannot divide a lower degree nonzero polynomial over a domain, since there we have $\, \deg(fg) = \deg f + \deg g,\,$ since a product of nonzero lead coef's remains nonzero. So your method is not so "clumsy" when viewed this way. Rather, it is quite natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof seems to be correct. Here is another way to prove the claim.

We know that $$\Bbb Z[x]/I \cong \Bbb F_3[X]/(X^3+X^2+1),$$ which has $3^3=27$ elements.

Assume that $x-1 \in I$. Then $(3,x-1) \subseteq I$, and since $(3,x-1)$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$, we would get $(3,x-1)=I$ or $I=(1)$. The latter case is not possible because $\Bbb Z[x]/I$ is not the trivial ring. Therefore we would have $$\Bbb Z[x]/I \cong \Bbb F_3[X]/(X-1) \cong \Bbb F_3$$ which has $3 \neq 27$ elements ; contradiction.

Comment: @Surb : let $f : \Bbb Z[X] \to \Bbb F_3[X]/(X^3+X^2+1)$ be the ring morphism defined by $f(a_0+\dots+a_nX^n) = \bar{a_0}+\cdots +\bar{a_n}X^n \pmod{X^3+X^2+1}$ where $\bar c = c \pmod 3$. It is surjective, and its kernel is $I$.